# Background / transparency of legend does not change

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made plots using the following code:

```
plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.scatter(x['num_xcoord'], x['num_ycoord'], c='#5477B3')
plt.gca().legend(('lead')) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

The plt.gca().legend line is used to edit the items in the legend, as I have different type of points, but for the sake of simplicity I left out these lines of code.

Currently, the legend does not show a border, or a background. I like the legend to have a white background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style you are using, `'seaborn'`, does not use a legend border or background color. If you want to keep the style and add a frame and white background, you can do this by adding `frameon = True` and `facecolor = 'white'` to the legend.